# Unable to convert moment.js formatted date to valid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Unable to convert moment.js formatted date to valid date using

```
new Date('08-Mar-19 06:01 AM') // Gives invalid date in IE
```

Note: it doesn't work in IE. Only works in Chrome.

Actually i got the format ('08-Mar-19 06:01 AM') using moment.js

```
const date = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.S'); // from "2019-03-08T06:01:52-05:00"
return date.isValid() ? date.format('DD-MMM-YY hh:mm A') : value;
```

i tried by parsing using moment.js still doesn't work.

```
new Date('08-Mar-19 06:01 AM') // Gives invalid date in IE
```

Expected:

```
new Date('08-Mar-19 06:01 AM');
Fri Mar 08 2019 06:01:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Actual:

```
new Date('08-Mar-19 06:01 AM'); // Invalid date
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the format of the string you are parsing with moment explicitly? E.g., `moment("08-Mar-19 06:01 AM").format("DD-MMM-YY hh:mm A")`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732164 answer might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much @thmsdnnr.
It helped me with your solution
I slightly modified by following...
new Date(moment(value, 'D-MMM-YYYY').format())